# Loading a Kotlin main class from a Gradle Fat Jar fails

Tags: kotlin, gradle, executable-jar

Based on other answers here I am using this Gradle build to create a fat/uber/shaded Jar with my command line tool and a number of JDBC drivers:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar

dependencies {
    api(project(":db2xls"))
    api("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    api("com.h2database:h2:1.4.200")
    api("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16")
    api("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.21")
    api("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre11")
}

val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
    manifest {
        attributes["Implementation-Title"] = "DB2XLS Bundle"
        attributes["Implementation-Version"] = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt"
    }
    from(
        configurations.compile.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) },
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
    )
    with(tasks.jar.get() as CopySpec)
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(fatJar)
    }
}
```

The build produces a JAR file that looks ok when inspecting with a ZIP tool, but it fails to execute:

```sh
$ java -jar db2xls-bundle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
```

The same goes if I use a classpath instead:

```sh
$ java -cp db2xls-bundle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
Error: Could not find or load main class de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
```

The class file seems to be there, though:

```sh
$ jar -t --file db2xls-bundle-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  | grep Db2XlsKt
de/peterbecker/xls/Db2XlsKt$logger$1.class
de/peterbecker/xls/Db2XlsKt$processQuery$1.class
de/peterbecker/xls/Db2XlsKt$toLists$$inlined$use$lambda$1.class
de/peterbecker/xls/Db2XlsKt.class
```

And the normal JAR seems to find load the class as expected (then failing on the lack of a depdency):

```sh
$ java -cp db2xls-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
Error: Unable to initialize main class de.peterbecker.xls.Db2XlsKt
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException
```

What am I doing wrong?

The full code is available at https://github.com/peterbecker/xls-utils/tree/fat_jar